# What do the star blocks do in Snake VS Block?

Tags: snake-vs-block

Occasionally while playing Snake VS Block, I'll see a star icon on a block. These blocks usually have fairly high numbers, so they can be difficult to break if you don't have a lot of health.

What do the star blocks do in Snake VS Block?

[image: Green star block labeled 25]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [IOSSnoops.com](https://www.iosnoops.com/appinfo/snake-vs-block-for-iphone-and-ipad/1233739175), **the star blocks are bonus blocks that grant temporary invincibility.**

This is confirmed by [the game’s iTunes page](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snake-vs-block/id1233739175?mt=8).  (Look in the "Latest Updates" area).

> **What's New in Version 1.19**
>
> - New Bonus Block! The Star block make you invincible during a short period of time.
>     Use it wisely to make big scores!